# Custom metrics (Disk-space-utilization) is missing on the AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a cloudwatch alarm for the diskspace-utilization.
I've folowed the AWS doc below

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html

It is creating the cron on my instance and I've checked my system log as well.

> Sep 22 12:20:01 ip-#### CRON[13921]: (ubuntu) CMD
>    (~/volumeAlarm/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl 
>    --disk-space-util --disk-space-avail --disk-space-used --disk-path=/ --from-cron)
>
> Sep 22 12:20:13 ip-#### CRON[13920]: (ubuntu) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)

also manually running the command,

> ./mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util --disk-space-avail
>   --disk-space-used --disk-path=/

shows the result,

> print() on closed filehandle MDATA at CloudWatchClient.pm line 167.
>
> Successfully reported metrics to CloudWatch. Reference Id:####

But there is no metrics in the aws console, So that I can set the alarm,

Please help, If someone solved the problem.

Comment: Did you make sure your ec2 instance has the correct permission  on action "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"?

Comment: Are you looking at the correct region in the AWS console? Is it in the same region as the instance?

Comment: yes I'm looking in the same region, as I've checked the metric info that as the same instance id that I am looking  @helloV

Comment: how to check permission on action "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"? @mostafazh

Comment: in the Getting started section, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html#mon-scripts-getstarted ... did you set the values AWSAccessKeyId and AWSSecretKey in the `awscreds.conf` file or you used IAM Roles?

Comment: yes, I've set these values. @mostafazh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> CloudWatch scripts will get the instance's meta data and write it to a
>   local file /var/tmp/aws-mon/instance-id, if the file or folder has
>   incorrect permission that the script cannot write to file
>   /var/tmp/aws-mon/instance-id, then it may throw error like "print() on
>   closed filehandle MDATA at CloudWatchClient.pm line 167". Sorry for
>   making assumption. A possible scenario is: the root user executed the
>   mon-get-instance-stats.pl or mon-put-instance-data.pl scripts
>   initially, and the scripts has generated the file/folder on place,
>   then the root user switched back to different user and execute the
>   CloudWatch scripts again, this error shows up. To fix this, you need
>   to remove the folder /var/tmp/aws-mon/, and re-execute the CloudWatch
>   scripts to re-generate the folder and files again.

This is the support answer that I get from the aws support on having the same issue may be it will help u too. Also do check your AWSAccessKey for the EC2 instance as well.